# onFling never triggers, but onDown does for ListView item

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector

im a beginner with android and for a couple of hours now i am stuck on a problem that seems to me should be not that hard. Im trying to use onFling on a ListView item. Ive found a couple of examples and very similar questions here, but none of the answers worked in my case.

I have a customAdapter in which i call my custom OnTouchListener.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(context, position));
```

Then i put the GestureDetector into MyTouchListener and called it in its onTouch.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    gdt.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //Code for drag and dropping
    }


final GestureDetectorCompat gdt = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new GestureListener());


private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {



    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event){
        Log.i("gwa", "gwa");
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.i("bla", "bla");
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Log.i("TouchListener", "swipe to Left");
            return false; // Right to left
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Log.i("TouchListener", "swipe to Right");
            return true; // Left to right
        }

        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return true; // Bottom to top
        }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return true; // Top to bottom
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The onDown works and outputs the log. But whatever i have tried so far the onFling seems to never be triggered.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  ListViews handle scrolling for you.  Trying to override/mess with what its doing is probably not safe.

Comment: looks like you are **using and then defining** `gdt` in your onTouch method.

Comment: @GabeSechan What do you mean? My intention is to delete an item when i swipe it so the left. ListView can already do that?

Comment: No, but ListView already has extensive touch handling for scroll.  Interfering with that may lead to bugs.

Comment: @petey Yes, is that incorrect? I am passing the context of the MainActivity to it though.

Comment: Yea,  that is not optimal for your needs. Can you edit your question to include the full `MyTouchListener` class?